# Windows Configuration Designer installation problem

Tags: windows

I am trying to use the Windows Configuration Designer app, but I can't run it correctly. When I install it from the Windows Store, and I try to init it, it shows this error:

[image]

This error prevents me to see all project options in the app. It only shows the advanced provisioning. When I try to create an advanced provisioning it trhows this error:

[image]

Do you know how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What error is it? It asked you to refer to log file to find out.

Comment: This is part of the log of the first error:

This is the first one:
12/15/2021 1:59:57 PM Error Could not start ICD web server.

And the second one:
12/15/2021 2:04:32 PM Error Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Wasn't the error followed by a proper exception and stack? Like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/667fc3a6-48d7-4f57-ab45-11ff169b2d64/windows-icd-unexpected-error-at-startup?forum=win10itprosetup) for example. Please edit the full error into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solutions. The problem was because of the windows antivirus. It is necessary to disable it to be able to use the program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).